# How to open an app in minimzed mode using Python?

Tags: python, windows, process, app-startup, minimized

```
app_paths = {
    "obsidian": "C:\\Users\\athth\\AppData\\Local\\Obsidian\\Obsidian.exe",
    "postman": "C:\\Users\\athth\\AppData\\Local\\Postman\Postman.exe",
    # "docker": "C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\Docker Desktop.exe",
    # Add more apps and their paths here
}



for app, path in app_paths.items():
    if app == "obsidian":
        # Start obsidian normally
        subprocess.Popen([path])    
    else:
        # Start other apps minimized
        SW_MINIMIZE = 6
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE
        subprocess.Popen([path], startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

In this code (this is the answer given in StackOverflow previously to someone else) I cannot open postman in minimized mode. It's opening in normal windows just like the Obsidian app, I'm working in windows